# How can I get my model output file after training has completed for this translation task?

Tags: python, deep-learning, translation, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am working on a diacritization project for the Yoruba language. It is a Nigerian Language.

I am using HuggingFace [codebase](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/translation) to perform my work. The training, evaluation and prediction phases work well. However, I cannot see the model output anywhere. How can I get it? What should I do to get this file. I need to deploy it on a web server.

See the command I used to train the model:

```bash
CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0 python run_translation.py --model_name_or_path Davlan/oyo-t5-small --do_train --do_eval --source_lang unyo --target_lang dcyo --source_prefix "<unyo2dcyo>: " --train_file data_prep_eng/output_data/bible_train.json --validation_file data_prep_eng/output_data/dev.json --test_file data_prep_eng/output_data/test.json --output_dir oyot5_small_unyo_dcyo_bible --max_source_length 512 --max_target_length 512 --per_device_train_batch_size=24 --per_device_eval_batch_size=24 --num_train_epochs 3 --overwrite_output_dir --predict_with_generate --save_steps 10000 --num_beams 10 --do_predict
```

The `run_translation.py` file is just a direct [copy](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/examples/pytorch/translation/run_translation.py) from the HuggingFace repo.

is there a command I'm missing to get this model?

See the output of my model after it completed training, evaluate and predict steps

[image: Model output directory]

Comment: what do you mean by model output? the folder `output_dir` has the model and that folder can be used in the web server

Comment: Hi @Jeril , how can the model be used in the web server? can you point me to a resource that shows how? I just need a model that can run on mobile devices and looking at Hugging Face Transformers docs, there's a way to convert my model from here to `tflite`. The challenge is I do not know how or where is even the model file. I need this model file. I was told that the model would be saved as `pytorch_model.bin` but I only see `training_args.bin` there.

Comment: if you want to use the model in a mobile device you can try converting your model to `ONNX` format. Better option would be to expose your model as an API and consume the API in the mobile device. After saving the model in the `output_dir` are you able to load the model again?

Comment: Thanks @Jeril. I plan to use it ONNX.

Answer (score 0):

So, after days of searching this is a resolved issue by the HuggingFace team. You can find it [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/28076). You also need to update your transformers library. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77759913/10348011) StackOverflow

Models are no longer named as `pytorch_model.bin`. They are named as `model.safetensors`.